# PowerShell v1 Script Prompting for Password

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to add remote server authentication to a PS1 batch file script.

So I can do this:

```
Copy-Item  $src $destination -Credential $Creds
```

I created a password file that for now is in the same directory as the script. It simply contains the password string.

The line that causes the prompt:

```
  Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File password.txt
```

When I remove the Read-Host command, the prompt goes away and the script executes as expected.

**Question**
What's the correct way to do remote server authentication?

**Here is the new code in context of the script:**

```
[...]

  if(-not(Test-Path $destination)){mkdir $destination | out-null}

  Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File password.txt
  $PW = Get-Content password.txt | ConvertTo-Securestring
  $Creds = New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Argumentlist "SERVER02\Administrator",$PW

ForEach ($sourcefile In $(Get-ChildItem $source | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "Daily_Reviews\[\d{1,12}-\d{1,12}\].journal" }))
{ 

      [...]

      Copy-Item  $src $destination -Credential $Creds

      [...]

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to read in the password without having a prompt? or is the authentication you're using not working?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't worried about portability of the password file between machines, you can use this fairly secure approach:

```
# Capture once and store to file - DON'T PUT THIS PART IN YOUR SCRIPT
$passwd = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$encpwd = ConvertFrom-SecureString $passwd
$encpwd
$encpwd > $path\password.bin

# Later pull this in and restore to a secure string
$encpwd = Get-Content $path\password.bin
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $encpwd

$cred = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'john',$passwd
$cred

# NOTE: The "secret" required to rehyrdate correctly is stored in DPAPI - consequence:
#       You can only rehydrate on the same machine that did the ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

If you need to debug this to see if $passwd is correct you can execute this while debugging:

```
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($passwd)
$str =  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($bstr)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($bstr)
$str
```